# Use of Selenium WITHOUT Chrome?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have worked on selenium project in python which uses both chrome and its driver.

For security reasons the customer doesn't want to use chrome, firefox etc... as each days security bugs are discovered in those browsers (highly sensitive data are stored on his machine and he doesn't want to risk it).

What can be done to solve this issue? What other alternatives are there so I can change my code accordingly.

Comment: Offtop but... every browser is gonna have security bugs. The fact that they are discovered for those browsers only means that enough people give a crap about security and they are more likely to be patched than the less popular alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Your two main options are

1. Most secure option

   - If your project is really *that* sensitive (national security), your only option is to air gap<sup>1</sup> all systems
   - ensure that nobody can breach that air gap, such as with USB sticks in the staff car park<sup>2</sup>, perhaps by putting your infrastructure on Bouvet Island.
   - Most projects (99.999%) do not need this level of security.
2. Slightly less secure, significantly more practical.

   - Ensure that the version of Chrome that selenium is using is always the latest and greatest, with the most up to date security patches applied.
   - Run your chrome containers in an environment that has limited access to the Internet.

     - Allow incoming and outgoing requests from only certain countries.
     - Allow only certain ports to be open.

Side note, never use block lists, only use allow lists.

- Block lists

  - block this stuff only
  - allow everything else
- Allow lists

  - allow this stuff only
  - block everything else

Chrome is maintained by Google, a company who,

- is huge, so has the funds necessary to keep their products patched
- has a vested interest in browser security; they want to ensure that users can continue to click on Google ads.

I would also strongly suggest contributing to the Selenium project, as it is FOSS and needs support.

Life is all about risk mitigation strategies. I could get run over by a bus tomorrow, but I'm not going to ban all buses to mitigate that risk, I'll just look both ways before I cross. Equally, someone might discover a bug in Chrome tomorrow, but does that mean you should stop using the most popular browser on the the planet to test your code? Probably not.

---

1. Buttice, C. (2021). What is an Air Gap? - Definition from Techopedia. [online] Techopedia. Available at: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/17037/air-gap [Accessed 20 Apr. 2022].
2. Pompon, R. (2018). Attacking Air-Gap-Segregated Computers. [online] F5 Labs. Available at: https://www.f5.com/labs/articles/cisotociso/attacking-air-gap-segregated-computers.

‌

Comment: Hi, would docket containers help here, where can I start from

Comment: If you are running in a cloud provider such as AWS, then running your infra inside a locked down Virtual Private Cloud would be your first step.